# Выполнить команду в указанной папке по SSH

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh, pipelines, bitbucket-pipelines

Использую Pipelines для деплоя.
Нужно выполнить команду в указанной папке.

```
- ssh xfinityphp@185.***.217.*** cd /home/xfinityphp/sms-receive-gateway/app
- ssh xfinityphp@185.***.217.*** docker-compose up -d
```

Ничего не работает.

```
- ssh xfinityphp@185.***.217.*** cd /home/xfinityphp/sms-receive-gateway/app && docker-compose up -d
```

При такой записи тоже.

Что нужно укзаать чтобы выполнить команду в нужной мне папке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько решений, первое уже указал [mymedia](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/942644/182954)

```
- ssh user@host 'cd /my/work/path; docker-compose up -d'
- ssh user@host 'cd /my/work/path && docker-compose up -d'
```

Другой, но похожий подход - можно создать/создавать промежуточный скрипт управления (например run.sh):

```
# ci
# ...
variables:
  SSH_WD: /my/work/path
script:
  - cat docker/prod/run.sh | ssh user@host "cat > ${SSH_WD}/run.sh"
  - ssh user@host "chmod +x ${SSH_WD}/run.sh"     
  - ssh user@host "${SSH_WD}/run.sh"
# ...
```

и примерно в `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -xe

# здесь можно использовать "любую" логику
# управления перезапуском сервисов или приложения в целом 

cd /my/work/path

docker-compose stop

#docker-compose down
#docker pull my/image:latest

docker-compose up -d

exit 0
```

Да, это сложнее, но открывает доп. возможности в управления, плюс скрипт управления храним в git.

Генерирую подобные файлы автоматически при сборке и развертывании, это дает возможность вносить корректировки, добавлять логику, добавлять хуки или проверки, использовать переменные и т.д. Скажу больше, что файлы `docker-compose.yml` также генерируются автоматически. По началу это казалось сложновато, но оказалось очень удобно для команды.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
- ssh xfinityphp@185.***.217.*** sh -c 'cd /home/xfinityphp/sms-receive-gateway/app && docker-compose up -d'
```

Чтобы изменить рабочий каталог, мы запускаем отдельный процесс оболочки, который вначале переходит в указанную папку, а затем запускает контейнер.

Comment: Возможно ли реализовать без cd?

Comment: cd - это встроенная команда оболочки, она указывает интерпретатору выполнить системный вызов [chdir](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/chdir.2.html) для смены каталога. Затем запускается Docker, наследуя рабочий каталог от родительского процесса. Не не имел дела особо с Docker, но если верить [документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/), правильная комбинация аргументов `-f` и `-p` решит ситуацию.